# newbie installing pip distribute

Tags: python, django, pip, distribute

I am trying to install `distribute` which is a required for installing `pip`(needed to use `django-selectable` functions).

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#python-os-support).

I downloaded `distribute` and ran `distribute_setup.py` , but now I don't know where to go, to have my `pip` installed.

They say:

> If your shell has the curl program you can do:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python distribute_setup.py
```

I guess I don't have `curl` program, my Python shell doesn't recognize `curl`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You dont need curl. Just go to the url, copy the contents to a file and save it as `distribute_setup.py` and run the python command

Comment: i already ran `distribute_setup.py`, how can i use pip now?

Comment: which environment are you using ? If *nix, just type `pip` on the terminal

Comment: where do i run this : `pip install django-selectable`

Comment: windows, and it don't recognize pip

Comment: at the terminal. Are you using windows, linux or mac ?

Comment: You can do `<path_to_python>/pip.exe install django-selectable` . Use google to figure such things out. You will get to know a lot  more

Comment: `the system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Ok. see where your pip.exe is (most likely in the lib) and execute the command. If not, google for how to add pip to the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `curl` from your python shell, you use it from the terminal

Comment: says it's not recognizable